# Given the inverse of a block matrix...

Tags: inverse, block-matrices

Given the inverse of a block matrix $X^{-1}$, where

$$ X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B
\end{array}\right). $$

A is $m\times n$ and B is $m\times(n-m)$.

Can I obtain the pseudo-inverse of A from $X^{-1}$?

Comment: I am sorry for the bad formatting of my text.

Comment: For future reference: an easy way to make those matrices is using `\pmatrix{}`.  For example, `$$\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}$$` renders as $$\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}$$ This works for MathJax (i.e. on this website), but does not work with LaTeX unless you add the necessary command.

Answer (score 2):

We note that
$$
I_n = X^{-1}X = X^{-1}\pmatrix{A&B} = \pmatrix{X^{-1}A & X^{-1}B}
$$
Thus, we have
$$
X^{-1}A = \pmatrix{
1&&0\\
&\ddots&\\
&&1\\
&0&\\
&&
}
$$
Where the matrix on the right is $m \times n$. If we take the first $m$ rows of $X^{-1}$ and call the resulting matrix $M$, we find that
$$
MA = \pmatrix{
1&&0\\
&\ddots&\\
0&&1\\
}
$$
Which means that $M$ is the left-sided pseudo inverse, depending on your definition.

Comment: It is such a beautiful and simple solution!  
However, I have tried with a random choice of $A$ and $B$, and $M$ is not equal to $(A^{T} \times A)^{-1} \times A^{T}$.  
Does it make sense? Or is it possible to have more than one matrix that multiplied by $A$ results in $I$?

Comment: Hmm, something might be wrong here.  I'll take another look

Comment: Nope, I was right.  Just make sure that your matrix $A$ has full rank, and there shouldn't be a problem (otherwise the pseudo-inverse may not be unique).

Comment: So, the truth is that $M$ is not necessarily equal to the pseudo-inverse. In fact, it depends on the choice of $B$.  As a consequence, there might have an infinity number of matrices that multiplied by $A$ results in $I$. (proof needed)  
For my problem, I will check whether I can use any of those matrices $M$. I will post later.  
Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Glad to help, good luck.

Comment: It seems the solution does not solve my problem.  So, let me put the problem in different terms...   
The way I presented the problem above is a simplification. In fact, I know *a priori* the value of $X \times (X^{T} \times X)^{-1}$. Through some manipulation, using inverse of block matrices, I ended up with  
$$\pmatrix{A&B} \times \pmatrix{A^{T}A&A^{T}B\\B^{T}A&B^{T}B}^{-1}$$   
   
What I really want as a solution is the value of $A \times (A^{T} \times A)^{-1}$

Comment: I have already tried many articles and tools, for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse, and the Matrix Inversion Lemma, but I did not managed to come to the solution. My original post was another try, because it seemed to me simpler than the original problem. Could anybody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You should probably post this as a new question.

Comment: I have posted a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605562/given-the-inverse-of-a-block-matrix-complete-problem