# Given the inverse of a block matrix - Complete problem

Tags: inverse, block-matrices

Given $X$ a block matrix

$$\pmatrix{A&B}$$

where $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $m \times (n−m)$.
I know *a priori* the value of $X \times (X^{T} \times X)^{-1}$.

Substituting $X$:

$$\pmatrix{A&B} \times \pmatrix{A^{T}A&A^{T}B\\B^{T}A&B^{T}B}^{-1}$$

I want to obtain the value of $A \times (A^{T} \times A)^{-1}$.
I have tried many articles and tools, for instance,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse

and the [Matrix Inversion Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), but I did not managed to find a solution.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The value of $A \times (A^{T} \times A)^{-1}$ is $(A^{T})^{-1}$, right ?

Comment: $A^{T}$ is not invertible. Its dimensions are $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Comment: Since $X\times (X^T \times X)^{-1} = X \times X^{-1} \times (X^T)^{-1} = (X^T)^{-1}$, you can find $X$ and there doesn't really seem to be a problem here ... unless there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: In fact, I want to know $A \times (A^{T} \times A)^{-1}$. But, I do not want to inverte any matrix. Since I know a priori $X \times (X^{T} \times X)^{-1}$, it would be useful to extract the information I want from the information I have. Your observation is perfectly right. But, it is not what I need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $X$ is square and you have the pseudo-inverse for it. Or in this case a left inverse. Well for a square matrix this is just the inverse. So I am going to answer the question of how to obtain the pseudo-inverse of a sub-portion of columns of a square matrix given the inverse for that matrix.

Knowns:
$$\pmatrix{A & B} = X$$
$$X^{-1} = \pmatrix{C \\ D}$$
so that $X^{-1}X = I$ gives
$$CA = I$$
a left inverse for the $A$ column matrix.
Given a general (left) inverse, for it to be the pseudo-inverse, it need be that $C^\top$ has the same column span as $A$ (see my profile page for a link where I show this about the pseudo-inverse). This will not be true in general, so we use the other rows of the inverse ($D$ with $DA = \mathbf{0}$) to make it happen. If $C^\top$ shared the same span as $A$, then because $D$ is the complementary space to $A$ then we would have $C^\top D = \mathbf{0}$. Thus the problem of finding the pseudo-inverse for $A$ given $X^{-1}$ is equivalent to orthogonalizing the rows of $C$ against the rows of $D$.

I apologize if my description is not perfectly understandable, so let me try some precise code. My code habit is python, let the matrix $X$ as x be a list of lists, and x_i the inverse. The function dot() is the obvious one (dot product):

```
for k in range(m-1, n, -1): # the rows in D, counting down from the last
  z = dot(x_i[k][:], x_i[k][:]) # get the norm squared
  for j in range(k): # orthogonalize the previous rows
    cross = dot(x_i[k][:],x_i[j][:])
    t = cross/z
    for i in range(m): x_i[j][i] -= t*x_i[k][i] # orthogonalize row j with row k
```

This will result in the pseudo-inverse in the first $n$ rows of the (now altered) inverse. This is less computation that finding the pseudo-inverse from scratch.

Comment: It looks a very intelligent solution. I will try with my problem and answer soon. Thank you very much!

Comment: So, this definitely looks like the perfect solution for my problem. The first $m$ rows of the orthogonalized matrix is the pseudo-inverse of $A$, as proposed, and can be used in the solution of my problem. Now, I have to check if the computational complexity is still worth. Is there any matrix solution for finding the orthogonalized matrix, or can it only be done iteractively? Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: For example if there is only one row in $D$ it is of course much better to do this, being only one count in the outer loop. But if the $C$ is the small one, then it is better to just start from scratch, so there are diminishing returns depending on $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Generally, $C$ is the small one. For instance, in one of the examples I will use this approach, $X$ is 32 $\times$ 32, $A$ is 32 $\times$ 2 and, consequently, $C$ and $D$ are, respectively, 2 $\times$ 32 and 30 $\times$ 32.

Comment: Well unfortunately it sounds like you are better off starting from scratch, since it is really just a 2 dimensional problem. Better to do that than to orthogonalize against 30 dimensions.